# I'm having trouble parsing and extracting ID value from an HTML with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to exract all the product URLs from this page (https://www.example.com/products) and then go to each URL, parse it and grab the ID values and print them. I wrote some code but it hasn't worked so far.
[Here's the list of products where I extract the URLs from][1]

[Here's the list of sizes where I extract the ID values from][2]

Here's the code that I wrote so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage_response = requests.get('https://www.example.com/products/', headers={'authority': 'www.example.com', 'method': 'GET', 'path': '/products/', 'scheme': 'https', 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0', 'referer': 'https://www.example.com/products', 'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate', 'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin', 'sec-fetch-user': '?1', 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'})

webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')

for li in soup.find_all("li", {"class":"productData"}):
    for link in li.select("a.fn"):
        url = link.get('href')
        webpage2_response = requests.get(url, headers={'authority': 'www.example.com', 'method': 'GET', 'path': '/products/', 'scheme': 'https', 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0', 'referer': 'https://www.example.com/products', 'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate', 'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin', 'sec-fetch-user': '?1', 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'})
        webpage2 = webpage_response2.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
        for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"size "}):
            for pid in div.select("a.selectSize"):
                print pid['id']


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMl7s.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX6T9.png
```

Comment: what's the actual url please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use BeautifulSoup too much, but you could try using the `re` module ([link](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.M)).  Here's something that will find all href urls, which means you'll either have to convert webpage_reponse.content from bytes to utf-8 or just use webpage_response.text:

UPDATE: Redid finding urls with finding id values:

```
import re

# Regular expression
ssize_pat = r'<a class\="selectSize" id\="(.*)"\s+?.*<\/a>'


# re.findall() with re.MULTILINE (or re.M) flag 
# to ignore newline characters (\n) in our search

ids = re.findall(ssize_pat, webpage_response.text, re.M)
```

Sample output from the example in the photo:

```
In [0]: ids
Out[0]: ['44927']
```

Comment: I actually was able to extract URLs just fine problem is when I make a GET request to URLs, parse them and extract the id="" values

Comment: @Rose I updated to look for IDs.  It will save you on having to write extensive code since results will be returned as a list.  Feel free to check it out.  I can't really get to the exact page in your demo to try since I'm in the US.

Comment: I appreciate your help, you're right your code is way shorter than mine

Comment: I have one more question. How do I print a URLs that contain those tag values?
e.g. www.example.com/add/[here goes the tag value]